# UserControl In List Binding

Tags: .net, wpf, binding, user-controls

Simple User Control

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DispValue}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>

public partial class UserControlDocFieldBaseB : UserControl
{
    public DocField DocField { get; set; }
    public UserControlDocFieldBaseB()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = DocField = new DocFieldString("ctorDocFieldString", "ctorDocFieldStringValue");
    }
    public UserControlDocFieldBaseB(DocField docField)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DocField = docField;
        this.DataContext = DocField;
    }
}
```

I want to bind it to a List
This has the correct number of items but the values are all from the default ctor ()
How do I get the UserControlDocFieldBaseB to use DocFields?

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DocFields}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:UserControlDocFieldBaseB DataContext="{Binding Path=.}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This works for a single item (ucB2 is a UserControlDocFieldBaseB)

```
ucB2.DataContext = docFieldSelected;
```

Comment: You overwrite `DataContext` when you do `this.DataContext = DocField`. Do you need it?

Comment: @dkozl If I take out DataContext="{Binding Path=.}" then no difference - still get the values assigned in the default ctror()

Comment: @dkozl That was the answer.  Please post and I will accept.

Comment: @dkozl Sorry dint see your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum up comments when you do:

```
this.DataContext = DocField = new DocFieldString("ctorDocFieldString", "ctorDocFieldStringValue");
```

you overwrite `DataContext` value that would be otherwise inherited. In fact you should not even need to bind `DataContext` of your `UserControl` as it should be inherited through visual tree

```
<local:UserControlDocFieldBaseB/>
```